# Parse.com push notification for web clients by making changes in installation class

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, push

I am trying to send push notifications to my web application.
Is there any way to send push notification to my web users using **parse.com**'s push service if i have the `GCM_SENDER_ID` and my `APP_ID` ?

Right now the procedure that i am thinking of using is this :

1). Run a service worker on my chrome client which gives me registration id of user . I save this in my installation class in deviceToken field . I also save my gcm_sender_id along with it.

2). Use parse.com's push sending api.

Will this work or do i need to directly make rest calls to https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send to send my message.

Comment: Why don't you try and share upcoming issues along the way with us?

Comment: finally went thru push notification api for web. Also parse is shutting down so there was no point in doing it using parse.com.